# Django best practice: number of model classes per file / directory structure

Tags: django

Another best-practice question to those with experience: How many models do you put in one file?

I've seen many examples that stuff all model classes into a single "models.py" file, which really feels wrong to me.  In previous projects using other stacks I've gone with one file per model class.  How is it done properly in Django for non-trivial applications with, say, 20 model classes?  What would the directory structure look like?

Comment: Why would you even have 20 models in an app in the first place?

Comment: Indeed. Thank you.  It would be multiple apps within the project/site.  I suppose that's what I meant when asking about the directory structure.

Comment: See my answer below, but if you're asking about directory structure, name them after *what they do.*  What do they represent?  What API do they expose to other applications?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Many people, especially those coming from the Rails world, get hung up on the term "application" and start throwing absolutely everything into a single app.  In Django, an application is a single-use module that does one thing and does it well.  Each application should be describable in one or two short sentences.  A "project" is a collection of applications unified by a settings file.  Even for something as complicated as an online store , something I'm discovering now, having more than four or five models in a single application is a warning sign: It was better that the `store` application (which has the shopping cart) be dependent upon upon the `product` application than have both in the same app.  The same was true of `invoices` and `payments`, and so on.

Take a look at [Django in the Real World](http://assets.en.oreilly.com/1/event/27/Django%20in%20the%20Real%20World%20Presentation.pdf), Jacob Kaplan-Moss's presentation about how to write Django applications.

A Django application is encapsulation: it describes one simple object (or collection of objects) and its API.  Having 20 models sounds like you don't have a clean API, and therefore a clear concept, of what this app does.

The answer you want is "it depends on what your application does."  To that end, what the Hell does an application with 20 models *do*, anyway?  Grab your copy of *Refactoring* and have fun.

Comment: Thanks to both you and Ignacio for pointing out the flaw in my phrasing of the question.  Do you, then, have these four or five models in each application's models.py file?

Comment: Yes, usually.  They represent a single coherent thought.  I think the most complicated app I ever did was a Film company's library: Film, Participant (actor, director, writer, etc), Festivals, Awards, all related to the film.  I could have broken those out into individual apps, and used Django's relationship manager make them available to templates, I suppose.  But it was four models, all told.    The idea is that they all form one coherent thought: "A Film and its Metadata."  Or whatever.  "Shopping Carts in a Store."  "Stories with Scenes, scenes' Characters and Settings."  One idea per app.

Comment: Hmm.  Perhaps I'm over-normalizing for Django?

Comment: Thanks for the link to "Django in the Real World", it's incredibly informative.

Comment: Does anyone know if there is a video presentation of the presentation. I've had a Google but can't seem to find it.